# how to select only non empty columns of a table from database

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I have a table with 46 columns in my database, In these 46 columns 25 or 26 are mostly empty.
when I select all columns by some condition I want only those column will select which have some data in it

Comment: Every row in a select statement has the same number of columns. Could you please clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: like I have 30 columns and 27 rows in a table but 14 column are empty in all 27 rows how to select the remaining non empty columns

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query to show you the not null columns' names:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 4294967295;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(
' SELECT ',QUOTE(COLUMN_NAME),
' FROM   table_name',
' WHERE `',REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, '`', '``'),'` IS NOT NULL',
' HAVING COUNT(*)'
) SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
INTO   @sql
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name';

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ed96/5/3)

And then just excute these columns manualy:

```
 SELECT column_name3, column_name8 FROM Table_Name;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ed96/7/4)